# Parse jobs are not running on schedules timing interval

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have a 7 jobs scheduled at different times. Sometimes the jobs run fine, but now, they are not. They stopped running on scheduled time. I have to run them manually.  Also it is not running nor showing any error.

I don't understand why this is happening suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is having problem with their background jobs. For many people their jobs are stuck in "pending".

For more info check https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/846543168788397/.